# rails rotum object belonging to the user object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, controller

I have 2 controllers User and Rota. I want the user to be able to create their own Rota but only be able to edit, show and destroy their own. I need to be able to code so that my  rotum object belongs to the user object.

ROTA CONTROLLER:

```
 class RotaController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :html, :xml, :json
   before_action :set_rotum, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
   def edit
  @rotum = @user.rota.find params[:id]
  end
   def index
     @rota = Rotum.all
     respond_with(@rota)
   end

   def show
     respond_with(@rotum)
   end

   def new
     @rotum = Rotum.new
     respond_with(@rotum)
   end

   def edit
   end

   def create
     @rotum = Rotum.new(rotum_params)
     @rotum.save
     respond_with(@rotum)
   end

   def update
     @rotum.update(rotum_params)
     respond_with(@rotum)
   end

   def destroy
     @rotum.destroy
     respond_with(@rotum)
   end

   private

   def set_rotum
     @rotum = current_user.rotums.find(params[:id])
     if @rotum.nil?
       render :html => "Not authorized", :status => 401
     end
   end

   def rotum_params
     params.require(:rotum).permit(:name, :email, :mobile, :category)
   end
 end
```

USER CONTROLLER

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate_user!
   after_action :verify_authorized

   def index
     @users = User.all
     authorize User
   end

   def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     authorize @user
   end

   def update
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     authorize @user
     if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
       redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
     else
       redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
     end
   end

   def destroy
     user = User.find(params[:id])
     authorize user
     user.destroy
     redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
   end


   def edit
   @rotum = @user.rota.find params[:id]
   end

   private

   def secure_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:role)
   end
 end
```

So far my rota allows anyone to create, show, edit and destroy the rota on the rotas page. I only want the user to be able to edit only THEIR OWN rota that they created. For that I have been told tell the rota object to belong to the user object. How can I do this in my controllers or models.

USER MODEL

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :rota, dependent: :destroy

  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

ROTUM MODEL

```
 class Rotum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
 end
```

I get the error:

NoMethodError at /rota/15

undefined method `rotums' for #

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing your models, so I'm assuming that you have a `has_many` relationship

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rota, dependent: :destroy
end

class Rotum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

then in your controller you can use the following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ....
  def edit
    @rotum = @user.rota.find params[:id]
  end
```

Note that this will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if a user is triying to edit a rotum that does not belong to him.

You can avoid that problem with the following:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ....
  def edit
    @rotum = @user.rota.find_by id: params[:id] # returns nil in case the record does not exist or does not belong to @user
    redirect_to "somewhere", alert: 'You cannot edit this element' if @rotum.blank?
  end
```

Comment: Ive put what i've edited in my classes and edited my post above to show you my models. I have done what you tell me but when I click Create Rotum or try to delete existing. It gives me the errorNoMethodError at /rota/15undefined method `rotums' for #<User:0x00000005a7fcb0>@Fer

Comment: Looks like it happens in your `rota_controller#set_rotum`. You have a @rotum = current_user.rotums ... use @rotum = current_user.rota ... instead

Comment: Hi @Fer I tried that and now i get the error, Unknown column 'rota.user_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: your rota table should have a user_id column (the foreign key for the relationship). Create a migration to add it.

Comment: I have edited the rota table so that it includes a user_id as an integer. (foreign key).  When I create a rota. It displays  Couldn't find Rotum with 'id'=2 [WHERE `rota`.`user_id` = ?]. I realise that active record needs to find a user who has created a rota entry. When I check the IRB the rota is still created when I do Rotum.all but it shows that error when doing it on  the web page.

Comment: Now when you create a rotum, you have to assign the user id to the current_user.id. If not, the user_id will be null and no one will be able to access it (which is what you asked for if I understood you well)

Comment: my main aim was so that nobody could edit any one else’s created Rotum apart from their own. I want the admin to be able to edit everything and the user to be able to create, show, edit and destroy only their own rota. Right now i'm stuck because there is that error Couldn't find Rotum with 'id'=9 [WHERE `rota`.`user_id` = ?]. When anyone regardless admin or user tries to do anything at all with the rota. I've tried fiddling here and there but nothign seems to work...